# synthesizeToFile giving java.io.FileNotFoundException: Is a directory error

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am getting a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Is a directory
```

error when trying to synthesize tts to a file, (both from speech recognition and text input) When testing on an Android device using 4.1.2 os and it makes the audio file in the root directory instead of the folder I'm telling it to make the file in and then crashes with that error, Also the name of the file it creates in the root directory is:

```
K9 Remotespoken.wav //when it should be saved as: K9 Remote/spoken.wav
```

HOWEVER, when I test with my other device with android 7.0 os it does not crash or give that error, but it does not make the audio file at all either, What am I doing wrong?

And can someone please explain what and how to get the 4th argument in the function synthesizeToFile("theText",bundle,file,string) for the lolipop and up synthesizeToFile function? I know what the first 3 are and what they do, but the android developers documentation only says the string in the 4th argument is a unique identifier? please explain what that is, thanks

```
private String state;
private File Root;
public File myFilename; //used in lolipop +
public String msg; //used in pre lolipop

//ON CREATE EVENT
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        myFilename = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/K9 Remote");
        if (!myFilename.exists()) {
            myFilename.mkdirs();
            msg = myFilename.toString();
        }
    }

    //REST OF RELEVANT CODE
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 400) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> res = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String holdForGMS = String.valueOf(res.get(0));
            HDC = appPreferences.getInt("h_d_c", 0);
            float nPitch = appPreferences.getFloat("my_pitch", (float) 1.0);
            float nSpeed = appPreferences.getFloat("my_speed", (float) 1.0);
            tts.setSpeechRate(nSpeed);
            tts.setPitch(nPitch);
                if (HDC == 0) {
                    if (transmitter == 1 && remote == 0) {
                        speakIT(holdForGMS);
                    }
                    if (transmitter == 1 && remote == 1) {
                        sendIT(holdForGMS);
                    }
                }
                if (HDC > 0)
                    synthToFile(holdForGMS);
            }
        }
    } 

 public void synthToFile(String ultraSynth) {

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {//THIS IS PRODUCING THE ERROR
            this.tts.synthesizeToFile(ultraSynth, null, myFilename,"/spoken.wav");
            PitchPlayer();
        }else
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {//I DO NOT HAVE A DEVICE WITH THIS OS TO EVEN TEST IF THIS CODE IS WORKING 
            this.tts.synthesizeToFile(ultraSynth, null, msg+"/spoken.wav");
            PitchPlayer();
        }
        } catch
                (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.i("K9 Remote", "Failed, can't synthesize to file");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I solved the file issue and got it working, the file paths were just messed up, this is the changed code:         if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            myFilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/K9 Remote");
            if (!myFilename.exists()) {
                myFilename.mkdirs();
            }
        }
  }
 
  public void myMethod {
  
  File fileTo = new File(myFilename.toString() + "/spoken.wav"); 
  // use fileTo object to save your file in your new directory that was created in the onCreate method
  }
 
     }

Comment: But would still like an explanation on what the 4th argument in the synthesizeToFile function is, I changed it to the tts object's name, as a string: this.tts.synthesizeToFile(ultraSynth, null, fileTo, "tts"); but would like to know what this argument is for and/or what it does.